# pg_escape_string not working

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to use `pg_escape_string` in my `password` can anyone sugest me hows it is used? in my postgresql `insert` table

```
$query = "insert into vmobjects (guid,ipaddress,username,password,hostid,vmname,guestostype) values('".$guid."','".$ip."','".$username."','".$password."','".$hostid."','".$name."','".strtolower($os)."')";
```

I m using `$escaped = pg_escape_string($password);`

```
$query = "insert into vmobjects (guid,ipaddress,username,password,hostid,vmname,guestostype) values('".$guid."','".$ip."','".$username."','".$escaped ."','".$hostid."','".$name."','".strtolower($os)."')";
```

but it is not working
it wil not take my `& and +` string ... like if i insert `@#&$%&^*` as a password then `after @#` it shows `nul values` .... `pg_escape_string` not working

It wil takes `'~!@#$%^*()_=-`{}|][:"';<>?/.,'`except`& and +` string.

my backend table row insert `&` string as a `null value` and after `&` string `all values are null`
and In the case of `+ string this is only null`

**Plz Don't refer me the sites manual**

Ya I'm POSTing the contents of a form field via AJAX to a PHP script and using this code

```
if(!http)
            http = CreateObject();  

        nocache = Math.random();

        http.open('post', 'addvm.php');
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        http.onreadystatechange = SaveReply;

        http.send(params);
```

Comment: try `$escaped_password = pg_escape_string($password);` and then in your query replace `$password` with `$escaped_password`

Comment: it wil not take my & and + string ... like if i insert @#&$%&^* as a password then after @# it shows nul values ....

Comment: What do you get if you run print $query; in your code?  Are you connected to a pg database (you have to be for pg_escape_string to work)?

Comment: Are you certain the password is still correct right before the query? Before you do pg_escape_string? Problems with & and + sound like you are passing the password along in an url without using urlencode on it.

Comment: @ Eelke: what wil i do? for urlencode

Comment: @stan:)r u POSTing the contents of a form field via AJAX to a PHP script?

Comment: @stan:)so can u add this code in ur script ..

Comment: @stan:)ohkkkk u need to encode your params encodeURIComponent Note:-When you access $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST in PHP, you are retrieving values that have already been decoded.

Comment: @hary:) but still it is not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forget about `pg_escape_string` and similar "workarounds".

What you want are [prepared statements and bind parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or (in case you're unwilling to jump right in) at least [`pg_query_params`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php).

Answer (score 4):

Just use pg_query_params() to make things very simple:

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO vmobjects 
  (guid,ipaddress,username,password,hostid,vmname,guestostype) 
VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)"; // $1 to $7 are the placeholders
$result = pg_query_params(
  $connection, // your database connection should be here
  $query,      // the query itself, including placeholders
  array($guid,$ip,$username,$password,$hostid,$name,strtolower($os) // array with values
);
```

There is no need for pg_escape_string when using pg_query_params. pg_query_params is by far the most simple aproach for interaction with your database.

Comment: Now you know the bug is somewhere else in your code and not in the escaping of characters nor PostgreSQL. As said before, no database has problems with characters like & and +, these characters have no special meaning like ' or \.

Comment: bro help me can i add my whole coding in my question  ? can u help me ?

Comment: I don't think I can help you, the bug is somewhere else in your code, not in your SQL: The & and + never make it to your piece of SQL, PostgreSQL never receives these characters. And you don't show us the code. Start debugging as usual and you will find the bug.

Comment: @ Frank Heikens : okies bro i wil try

Answer (score 1):

I am almost sure that your problem is sending the content to backend, not to send it to database. In Url data, & and + signs are treated specially. However, unless you use AJAX like method you will not end up with problems. If you are using AJAX like method to post, use Url encode. If you are using an AJAX library, it may contain a method for that, if not, you can use webtoolkit version, which is a single file.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do here would be to encode the password and then enter it into the database. This way, you won't get any escaping problems.

A way to do this would be:

```
$escaped = md5($password);
```

And when you check if the password matches, do:

```
if (md5($user_entered_password) == $password)...
```

Comment: Another reason to encrypt it. Passwords should never be unencrypted.

But if you really want to use it unencrypted, try this:
    `pg_escape_string(utf8_encode($escaped));`

Comment: not really a solution if he has this problem with a password field he is probably going to get (or all ready has) it with other fields. On the other hand encrypting the password is excellent advice and I certainly second that advice thought MD5 is a bit weak especially without a salt. With a rainbow table it will be cracked in seconds.

Comment: @Stan: if the passwords are protecting sensitive data you really should encrypt them relying on people not having direct access to your database won't be enough. Your PHP scripts probably have a few security holes (it happens to the best). You may want to read http://www.jasypt.org/howtoencryptuserpasswords.html if you want to know how to properly encrypt your passwords. Most methods shown on the internet are to simplistic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 params = 
 "guid="      + encodeURIComponent(szguid)     + 
 "&username=" + encodeURIComponent(szusername) +
 "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(szpassword) +
 "&ip="       + encodeURIComponent(ip)         +
 "&name="     + encodeURIComponent(name)       +
 "&os="       + encodeURIComponent(os);
    //alert(params);
    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';//change cursor to wait

    if(!http)
        http = CreateObject();  

    nocache = Math.random();

    http.open('post', 'addvm.php');
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    http.onreadystatechange = SaveReply;
    http.send(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Google around, it looks like there is a problem with pg_escape_string() (and other pg_* function) with PHP 5.3 (see http://bugs.php.net). Din't yet find a definitive answer/solution (except perhaps downgrade to PHP 5.2 for a while).

Post Scriptum:
In my case (I'm using Ubuntu Maverick) I found the problem was fixed after perform an upgrade to the system (sudo apt-get upgrade)