# Is there PHP mysql_real_escape_string for postgresql?

Tags: php, postgresql

Is there PHP mysql_real_escape_string for postgresql? 
if yes then how ? please Give the Examples? & also the work of this string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternatively you could use prepared statements ([pg_prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php)) and placeholders (`$1`, `$2`, etc), and then give the arguments for the query in [pg_execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php). This would be my preferred way as it's not only cleaner, but also safer in the long run since there's no chance for SQL injections if you always use placeholders in prepared statements.

Comment: There's an example in the `pg_prepare` documentation page.

Answer (score 10):

See `pg_escape_string` at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029240/pg-escape-string-not-working not working ...plz help me

Comment: It wil takes '~!@#$%^*()_=-{}|][:"';<>?/.,'except& and +` string.

Answer (score 3):

Use [pg_query_params()](http://nl.php.net/pg_query_params):

```
<?php    
$result = pg_query_params(
      $dbconn, // database connection
      'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = $1 AND baz = $2', // query using placeholders
      array('value 1','value 2') // all values for the placeholders in a single array
    );
?>
```

Save and very eary to use.

Answer (score 2):

You have both `pg_escape_string` and `pg_escape_bytea` available.