# Escape SQL queries in PHP PostgreSQL

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, escaping

I have a website with lots of PHP files (really a lot...), which use the `pg_query` and `pg_exec` functions which do not 
escape the apostrophe in Postgre SQL queries.

However, for security reasons and the ability to store names with
apostrophe in my database I want to add an escaping mechanism for my database input. A possible solution is to go
through every PHP file and change the `pg_query` and `pg_exec` to use `pg_query_params` but it is both time consuming
and error prone. A good idea would be to somehow override the `pg_query` and `pg_exec` to wrapper functions that would 
do the escaping without having to change any PHP file but in this case I guess I will have to change PHP function
definitions and recompile it which is not very ideal.

So, the question is open and any ideas that would
allow to do what I want with minimum time consumption are very welcome.

Comment: so, you are calling your database from alot php files? and want to overwrite php functions to save you the hassle to rewrite it securely? please dont do so. This could be the time to rework your database in general. Because a lot PHP files dont mean all of them need to access the database directly (MVC)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030249/is-there-php-mysql-real-escape-string-for-postgresql

Comment: @ShyamK The questions are no way related

Comment: @Dr.Dan OP asks for escaping SQL queries while using PostgreSQL, right? So then its answer would be to use something like the answers stated in the question I linked, no?

Comment: @ShyamK No, it wouldn't. Read the problem **again carefuly**.

Comment: If it was possible to do what the question asks for, then there would be need to escape the parameters in code in the first place, it would be automated. How to do it? To find the parameter values inside the SQL statement, you need to parse the statement. To parse the statement, you need these parameters to be properly escaped => oops, chicken and egg problem!

Comment: Don't try to escape everything.  The better way to avoid SQL injection is to use parametrized queries.  http://bobby-tables.com/php.html gives examples of how to do this with PHP.  The wrapper that you are considering making already exists.  It is the PDO package.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect example of when a database layer and associated API will save you loads of time. A good solution would be to make a DB class as a singleton, which you can instantiate from anywhere in your app. A simple set of wrapper functions will allow you to make all queries to the DB go through one point, so you can then alter the way they work very easily. You can also change from one DB to another, or from one DB vendor to another without touching the rest of the app.

The problem you are having with escaping is properly solved by using the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) interface, instead of functions like pg_query(), which makes escaping unnecessary. Seeing as you'll have to alter everywhere in your app that uses the DB, you may as well refactor to use this pattern at the same time as it'll be the same amount of work.

```
class db_wrapper {

    // Singleton stuff
    private $instance;

    private function __construct() {
        // Connect to DB and store connection somewhere
    }

    public static function get_db() {
        if (isset($instance)) {
            return $instance;
        }
        return $instance = new db_wrapper();
    }

    // Public API

    public function query($sql, array $vars) {
        // Use PDO to connect to database and execute query
    }

}

// Other parts of your app look like this:

function do_something() {
    $db = db_wrapper::get_db();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column = :name";
    $params = array('name' => 'valuename');
    $result = $db->query($sql, $params);

    // Use $result for something. 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You post no code but I guess you have this:

```
$name = "O'Brian";
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM customer WHERE name='{$name}'");
```

... and you'd need to have this:

```
$name = "O'Brian";
$result = pg_query_params($conn, 'SELECT id FROM customer WHERE name=$1', array($name));
```

... but you think the task will consume an unreasonable amount of time.

While it's certainly complex, what alternatives do you have? You cannot override `pg_query()` but it'd be extremely simple to search and replace it for `my_pg_query()`. And now what? Your custom function will just see strings:

```
SELECT id FROM customer WHERE name='O'Brian'
SELECT id FROM customer WHERE name='foo' OR '1'='1'
```

Even if you manage to implement a bug-free SQL parser:

1. It won't work reliably with invalid SQL.
2. It won't be able to determine whether the query is the product of intentional SQL injection.

Just take it easy and fix queries one by one. It'll take time but possibly not as much as you think. Your app will be increasingly better as you progress.

Comment: "but you think the task will consume an unreasonable amount of time" means that it is premature optimization.  Rule 1 of Optimization Club is "do not optimize".  Rule 2 of Optimization Club is "do not optimize without measuring first."

Comment: No, it's not.  It is the concern that quoting somehow will make the database access slower that is premature optimization.

Comment: @AndyLester Oh, that... I meant that it'll take time to fix the code, which is the OP's concern.